# Google map search using Price Range

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to use google map to search places like restaurant or school but i want to search the places with their price ranges.I could not find any solution in google api documentation. I have found the site just like i wanted but got no clue. [See this reference](https://www.99acres.com/)
Can you guys give me any hints? I am really in need guys

Comment: please help me guys

Comment: https://www.99acres.com/ has this features of price ranging. How can we do that? or do we need to consult with google for it?

Answer (score 2):

Google Maps Places API searches have parameters for min and max prices that can be expressed in integers from 0 to 4.

> **minprice and maxprice (optional)** — Restricts results to only those places within the specified range. Valid values range between 0 (most affordable) to 4 (most expensive), inclusive. The exact amount indicated by a specific value will vary from region to region.

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests

https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#TextSearchRequests

Similar filter exists in the places library of Google Maps JavaScript API

> **minPriceLevel and maxPriceLevel (optional)** — Restricts results to only those places within the specified range. Valid values range between 0 (most affordable) to 4 (most expensive), inclusive.

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests

You should implement your logic based on these filters.

Comment: anything in maps query uri for user rating?